# Regarding Three js Animation

Tags: three.js

I am working with three js animation,in which I have a sphere in my scene.I want my mouse to be changed like hand whenever I place the cursor on that sphere.So how can I do it?

I have created a sphere like this.

```
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.8, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
);
sphere.position.set(12.8, 0, 0);
sphere.name="Hello";
```

scene.add(sphere);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `THREE.Raycaster()` and "mousemove" event listener for this purpose.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

var objects = [];
objects.push(sphere);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects;

function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; // hand-like cursor
    } else {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    };
};
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/6qjkrto6/) example